# Counting comparisons in Binary Search

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, binary

I've been given an assignment where I need to count the 'number of comparisons' a given Binary Search program makes.

The problem is the Binary Search uses an if, else if, else statement and it's not possible to insert a counter increment statement between these comparisons.

Is there a design method that's appropriate to keep count of comparisons to test efficiency?

There's another SO question on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913368/what-counts-as-a-binary-search-comparison) but the answer comments that the counter will be off by 1-2 increments. If a comparison is made every time a condition is checked, is it inaccurate to place it in a comparison body (which is only evaluated if true?).

In pseudocode I have:

```
binarysearch(array, k)
   counter = 0;
   x = 0;
   length = array.length

  while (0 <= length)
    int middle = length + x / 2;

     counter+1; 
     if (x is array[middle]) {print(counter) return middle;}
     else if (k < array[middle]) { x = middle - 1; counter + 1; }
     else { x = middle + 1; counter + 1; }

  Print(counter);
  Return -1;
```

Comment: Have you tested your implementation? Does it work?

Comment: No, it seems to produce more comparisons than were made (according to the theory.) I now have the counters in the body of each conditional, because another solution seems to suggest this is OK. I still really need to find out what the definition of a comparison is...

Comment: I mean does your program return proper index of the searched element? And does it really C#? I'm not a csharper, still it doesn't look like a valid C# code for me, though i may be wrong.

Comment: Oh, yeah the program works perfectly. It's not C#, it's pseudocode because I can't post the program — my university won't allow it.

Comment: The psuedo code you posted makes no sense. It can't possibly work because `middle` can never decrease. If you can't post the actual code, then at least post code that makes sense.

Comment: "then at least post code that makes sense" isn't very nice phrasing. The pseudocode I posted is actually incredibly close to the textbook example, and it's been working the whole period of assessment. middle will decrease, because r and l change. It doesn't matter that middle is being redeclared.

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is the Binary Search uses an if, else if, else statement
>   and it's not possible to insert a counter increment statement between
>   these comparisons.

The assertion you can't count the comparisons, because you can't increment in an `if`,  `else if` and `else` is wrong. Yes its true you cant always increment in a conditional statement the way you'd like. Though you can still count them.

Take for instance

```
If(some comparison)
{
   // if we get here we obviously made a comparison and it was true
   Comparisons +=1;
}
else if (some comparison)
{
   // If we get here we obviously made 2 comparisons
   // the first was false, this is true. 
   // However regardless, 2 Comparisons were made 
   Comparisons +=2;
}
else
{
   // if we get here we obviously made 2 comparisons both were false
   // however 2 comparisons were still made 
   Comparisons +=2;
}
```

Comment: That `+=1` will happen only once. Menas you can simplify this a lot.

Comment: I don't think I figured out what constitutes a comparison well enough. I used your method, and I end up with too many comparisons compared to the textbook (log_2n-1, or log_2n+1 depending on the item being in the array or not.) I did +1 for each statement instead, and now the unsuccessful case follows the expected growth, but the item present case does not (it's more like log_2n+0.6 instead of log_2n+1).

Answer (score 1):

Try somethig like this:

```
 binarysearch(array, k)
   counter = 0;
   x = 0;
   length = array.length

   while (0 <= length)
    int middle = length + x / 2;

     if ((++counter>0) and x is array[middle]) {print(counter) return middle;}
     else if ((++counter>0) and k < array[middle]) { x = middle - 1; }
     else { x = middle + 1; }

  Print(counter);
  Return -1;
```

(++counter>0) is always true and don't change the if condition